# Ansible - How to capture command output and save as a several variables

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

I am trying to write some automation using Ansible and I've come across a situation where I need to use multiple parts of a command output in a task later down the playbook.

I have a task that is going to run the command "lspci | grep Ethernet | grep Gigabit"

The output should look something like this (should be 2 lines of output):

```
"02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82575EB Gigabit Network Connection (rev 02)"
"02:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82575EB Gigabit Network Connection (rev 02)
```

Out of this output, I need to extract 4 pieces of information as variables.

var1 - I want the bus of the first line. Should be "02"

var2 - I want the function of the first line. Should be "0"

var3 - I want the bus of the second line. Should be "02"

var4 - I want the function of the second line. Should be "1"

How do I go about extracting the information from the output into these 4 variables? Doesn't necessarily have to be a single play that gets all 4 variables.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: have you tried using `register`? Show what you've tried and we can help.

Comment: If I use register, it will take the entire output string when i only want a very small subset of the string

Comment: it gives 'lines', so you can start plucking out pieces with Jinja.

Comment: Use `register` to save all output then use bash `grep` to get each variable. `- command: cat {{ all_output.stdout }} | grep # what you like`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As suggested, you should `register` the output of the command. After that, you can loop over the results and grab the parts you're interested in.

Working example:

```
- name: Fun with lspci output 
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
   - name: get Gigabit Ethernet adapters
     shell: lspci | grep Ethernet | grep Gigabit | awk '{print $1}'
     register: eth_adapters

   - name: use extracted info
     debug: msg="Adapter found, bus {{item.split(':')[0]}}, function {{item.split('.')[-1]}}"
     with_items: "{{eth_adapters.stdout_lines}}"
```

Note the use of `eth_adapters.stdout_lines` to get the command output as a list of items, and the `awk '{print $1}'` to only grab the bus info of the devices.

This example produces the following output:

```
PLAY [Fun with lspci output] ***************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [get Gigabit Ethernet adapters] *******************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [use extracted info] ******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=00:00.0) => {
    "item": "00:00.0", 
    "msg": "Adapter found, bus 00, function 0"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=00:01.0) => {
    "item": "00:01.0", 
    "msg": "Adapter found, bus 00, function 0"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=00:01.1) => {
    "item": "00:01.1", 
    "msg": "Adapter found, bus 00, function 1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=00:01.3) => {
    "item": "00:01.3", 
    "msg": "Adapter found, bus 00, function 3"
}


PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```